# Can you export iPhone application pieces from CS5 that you bundle together in your own Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, flash-cs5

I have a couple of small little Flash files that I've created and I want to export them in some fashion so that I can bundle them together into one iPhone application. So what I want is to be able to create a menu type system in an Xcode iPhone project and link to my Flash files when the user navigates to them from that menu.

I've seen that Adobe CS5 supports exporting .ipa files, but this isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

groomsy

Answer (score 0):

You can "un-pack" the ipa file and see what is inside. I'm not familiar with xcode, but perhaps you could pick out those files after they have compiled?